# Python Lookup table, similar to simulink

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

Hello could you please help me please? I need to make a look up table like in SIMULINK but in PYTHON.

Lets assume we have an efficiency map, an excel file where first column is a Y-value(Torque vector), first row is X-value(Speed vector), and a Efficiency matrix, or whatever the data stored in.

I need the function taking 2 inputs like SPEED and TORQUE and then it must give me Efficiency.

This is called MAP or Look Up table.

This look up table usually interpolates the values of table(matrix) if there is no exact entries but i dont know how to implement this interpolation.

### my pseudo-code would like this:

```
Efficiency= read.excel

speed=read.excel.first_column

torque=read.excel.first_row

def Lookuptable (X,Y)

efficiency=Lookuptable.iloc(Lookuptable[i],Lookuptable[j])
```

---

But here it does not interpolate plus its pseudocode and I need a python code.

So I basically need 2 features:

1. without for loop.
2. if the values are "in between" -> use interpolation.

Down there is a picture to illustrate the task:

[Look Up Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaUUa.png)

I was trying to read the next values, then comparing and doing a step back.

Comment: Do you have some example data and the result you hope to get after some demo lookups?

Comment: Just a guess, but it sounds like something you might find in `scipy`.

Comment: well its like input is X= [130,150], Y=[1500,1600] and Eff_map=[0.94,0.96; 0.88, 0.9] and if I use lookuptable(140,1550) I must get something like 0.935, firstly probably interpolate X[140,1500], then X[140,1600] and then X[140,1550].